# Excel percentage not changing properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image: Excel Sheet]

Is there a way to make E16 change accordingly when the percentage in C16 is changed? I want E16 to be showing as 70, not 99.70. I think the correct formula is =E16-(E16*C16), but how can I add that to the already existing E16 formula =IF(A16>0,D16*A16,"")? Do I need two IF statements? I wouldn't normally ask but no matter how much I have researched I can't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply the calculated value with `(1-C16)`:

```
=IF(A16>0,D16*A16*(1-C16),"")
```

Comment: Thanks man you're awesome. I spent the last 5 hours trying to figure this out being an excel noob n all.

Comment: Glad to help. In fact, @Bathsheba was like half a minute faster than me -- and his answer is more detailed. I think you should mark his answer as the best one.

Comment: @Schorsch: you can always edit your answer to make it more comprehensive. Do feel free to take facets from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The formula in E16 is simply `=(1 - C16) * D16 * A16`

`(1 - C16)` is the "percentage" actually paid, you need to multiply that by the quantity (which will be zero by default so there's no need for an `IF`), and the unit price.

If you want to be able to copy this formula down and don't want spurious zeros to appear in column E, then do indeed use a containing `IF`:

`=IF(A16, (1 - C16) * D16 * A16, "")`